# How to find last window lock/unlock time in c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

I want to find the wheather my machine(XP installed) is locked or unlocked today. Can anybody know how to achieve this in C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the [SessionSwitchEventHandlerDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.sessionswitcheventhandler.aspx) and log it every time they lock or unlock. Then you just consult your log.

[Here's](http://omegacoder.com/?p=516) some sample code.